# Validate name and surname using regex

Tags: regex, string

I am trying to write a regex for *name* and *surname*. They are made by one or more words that can be made only by alphabetical letter (I don't care initial capital letters).

I *would like* to match for both name and surname:

Names:

```
- Antony de Home April
- antony de Home April
- ANTONY de Home ApRil
- aNtOnY de Home April
- Antony de d'home APRil
- Antony de d'Home ApRil
- Antony de D'Home April
- Antony de d'HOME AprIL
- ...
```

Surname match the same cases as names.

I *would not* (no numbers or special characters):

Names:

```
- Antony1 de Home Ap*ril
- Antony_ de Home Apr+il
- Ant_ony de Home Apr#il
- Antony@ de Ho@me Apr^il
- ...
```

Surname match the same cases as names.

How I can write that?

---

**UPDATE**

I *would like* to match for both name and surname:

Names:

```
- Antòny de Homé April
- àntony de Home ùpril
- Antony de Home Aprìl
```

*If you have other suggestions for name and surname validation, let me look!*

Comment: This is stupid. I can, legally, rename myself to Antony1 Home.

Comment: From your desired cases, I gather apostrophes are acceptable, so you may want to clarify the "only by alphabetical letter" portion of your specification. Are there any other punctuation marks that are acceptable?

Comment: @Anders agreed, smells like homework.

Comment: What about, say, Eugène?

Comment: Yes, Eugène! I will update the question. If you have other suggestions, let me look!

Comment: How about **not** validating the name? Any name can be valid.

Comment: You may want to consider this: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @Jeremy Stein, I'd been looking for that link!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advice on how to validate names and surnames using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718266/advice-on-how-to-validate-names-and-surnames-using-regex)

Answer (score 1):

This sould be your regex:

```
[A-Za-z]+\s+['A-Za-z]+
```

Comment: No, letters are `\pL`, not `[A-Z]`.  And alphabetics are not just letters; they are [typically held](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Compatibility_Properties) to be `[\pL\pM\p{Nl}]`. And apostrophes are rather more than just `'`, sinc e you’ve forgotten `’` in that.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([a-Z]+)\s([a-Z]+)/
```

of course I make a number of assumptions with this regex.