# Advice on how to validate names and surnames using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to validate *name* and *surname* for my Ruby on Rails 3 application and so I have posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717874/validate-name-and-surname-using-regex). Someone adviced me to read the [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) article and now I am in trouble.

**What is the right way to validate names and surname?**

Regex is a way, but what should I be careful? Can you give me an overview?

Comment: About the most comprehensive regex you can come up with will be '.*'

Comment: @Bryan, actually you can do somehwhat better than that, since `.*` admits quite a few things that I hold to be bogus names, like those of length 0 (maybe) and those without any printing characters in them (like all backspaces).

Comment: @tchrist: but in all seriousness, why do you care? If someone wishes to identify themselves as "^H^H^H" why does it matter? It's all just bits to the computer.

Comment: @Bryan: Because I’d like to be able to put some ink down on the page after something like `Name:        `. That’s why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to validate names is:

1. Accept any and all possible Unicode characters.
2. Reject inputs of length 0.
3. Make sure the result has at least one character that is neither of type `\pM`, `\pZ`, nor `\pC`; i.e., is neither one of the combining marks, separators, nor other (usually control) characters. A character class like `[^\pM\pC\pZ]` should suffice.

There: easy as can be. You will probably need Ruby 1.9 to do this properly, though.

Comment: This seems like exactly what I need, but when using this in a Rails validator I'm getting "warning: invalid Unicode Property \p: /[^\pM\pC\pZ]/" - any ideas?

Comment: Add `u` to the end of your exp: `/^[..]$/u`

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, you cannot validate names and surnames other than to verify they are not null*. By filling in a form that asks for a name, somebody is declaring "this is my name", and if someone says "this is my name", you should believe them because they are the ultimate authority of what is their name.

* even then, it's perfectly valid for people to have a single name rather than two or three, and there has been one instance of an individual who didn't actually have a name. He gave himself a symbol instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have read that article, you have seen that it is not possible to validate a name, with or without regular expressions.

So don't even go there. If people want to call themselves Tarquin Fin-tim-lin-bin-whin-bim-lim-bus-stop-F'tang-F'tang-Olé-Biscuitbarrel ([it *has* happened!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Election_Night_Special) see the section "Cultural references"), who are you to deny it to them?

Comment: That's *Mr.* Olé-Biscuitbarrel to you (I think that's going to become my favorite pseudonym going forward...)

Comment: What?! Are you mocking me? That's my given name! :-)